# Pig - outputSchema - create schema for tuple

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig, cloudera

Im trying to define output schema which should be Tuple that contains another two tuples, i.e  `stats:tuple(c:tuple(),d:tuple)`.

The code below doesnt work as it was intended. It somehow produces structure as:

```
stats:tuple(b:tuple(c:tuple(),d:tuple()))
```

Below is output produced by describe.

```
sourceData: {com.mortardata.pig.dataspliter_36: (stats: ((name: chararray,customerId: chararray,VIN: chararray,birth_date: chararray,fuel_mileage: chararray,fuel_consumption: chararray),(name: chararray,customerId: chararray,VIN: chararray,birth_date: chararray,fuel_mileage: chararray,fuel_consumption: chararray)))}
```

Is it possible to create structure as below, which means i need to remove tuple b from the previous example.

```
grunt> describe sourceData;
sourceData: {t: (s: (name: chararray,customerId: chararray,VIN: chararray,birth_date: chararray,fuel_mileage: chararray,fuel_consumption: chararray),n: (name: chararray,customerId: chararray,VIN: chararray,birth_date: chararray,fuel_mileage: chararray,fuel_consumption: chararray))}
```

The below code doesnt work as expected.

```
  public Schema outputSchema(Schema input) {
            Schema sensTuple = new Schema();
            sensTuple.add(new Schema.FieldSchema("name", DataType.CHARARRAY));
            sensTuple.add(new Schema.FieldSchema("customerId", DataType.CHARARRAY));
            sensTuple.add(new Schema.FieldSchema("VIN", DataType.CHARARRAY));
            sensTuple.add(new Schema.FieldSchema("birth_date", DataType.CHARARRAY));
            sensTuple.add(new Schema.FieldSchema("fuel_mileage", DataType.CHARARRAY));
            sensTuple.add(new Schema.FieldSchema("fuel_consumption", DataType.CHARARRAY));

            Schema nonSensTuple = new Schema();
            nonSensTuple.add(new Schema.FieldSchema("name", DataType.CHARARRAY));
            nonSensTuple.add(new Schema.FieldSchema("customerId", DataType.CHARARRAY));
            nonSensTuple.add(new Schema.FieldSchema("VIN", DataType.CHARARRAY));
            nonSensTuple.add(new Schema.FieldSchema("birth_date", DataType.CHARARRAY));
            nonSensTuple.add(new Schema.FieldSchema("fuel_mileage", DataType.CHARARRAY));
            nonSensTuple.add(new Schema.FieldSchema("fuel_consumption", DataType.CHARARRAY));


            Schema parentTuple = new Schema();
            parentTuple.add(new Schema.FieldSchema(null, sensTuple, DataType.TUPLE));
            parentTuple.add(new Schema.FieldSchema(null, nonSensTuple, DataType.TUPLE));


            Schema outputSchema = new Schema();
                outputSchema.add(new Schema.FieldSchema("stats", parentTuple, DataType.TUPLE));

            return new Schema(new Schema.FieldSchema(getSchemaName(this.getClass().getName().toLowerCase(), input),
                    outputSchema, DataType.TUPLE));
```

The UDF's exec method returns:

```
    public Tuple exec(Tuple tuple) throws IOException {

              Tuple parentTuple  = mTupleFactory.newTuple();

              parentTuple.append(tuple1);
              parentTuple.append(tuple2);
```

thank you